# Get Facebook user data with Asp.net core Identity

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

First of all, I'm a complete beginner and don't even know if this question makes sense.

I am trying to make my first ASP.NET Core MVC application. For registration and login, I'm using Asp.Net Core Identity with Facebook authentication.

For the app, I would need to access the logged in users friends list from Facebook. As far as I understand I need to get a user access token to be able to query the Facebook Graph API. (Right?)

For the registration setup, I followed the tutorial provided by Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli

Now I am trying to achieve 2 things.

1.) Save logged in user Facebook ID and profile picture to another table in my database

2.) I want to get the friends list of the logged-in user within a method of a controller.

Below is part of the code of a controller for the table in my database to which I wish to save the ID and profile picture and where I wish to use the logged-in user friends list for comparison in a query.

```
namespace web.Controllers
{

    [Authorize]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PlanerContext _context;

        public UserController(PlanerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: User
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //GET USER FRIENDS LIST FROM FACEBOOK
            //var friendIdList = ...

            //Get data from Database
            string query = string.Format("Select * from users where userId IN ({0})",friendIdList);
            return View(await _context.Users.FromSqlRaw(query).ToListAsync());

        }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you explain what you tried and what you need help with? Or you just want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: I wrote the query, now I need to get the Access Token for the query to work. There is a table in Identity called AspNetUserTokens that should save user tokens but it doesn't for me. I have set options to `SaveTokens = True` in AddAuthentication. I'm guessing there's more to it but I can't find anything useful to help me. My question is this: How do I save an Access token of a logged-in user and use it in my query.